# How to prevent vents from leaking?

Tags: air-conditioning, moisture

It appears that in my house the cool air from the vents is causing moisture to condense around them and drip down the walls. Is there any way to prevent this? Also, is this in any way potentially harmful to me?[image: air]

Comment: Some additional information is needed here.  What's the relative humidity in the room?  Are you sure the water is condensing at the vent and not coming from the duct itself?

Comment: Noticing the water streaks do not go all the way to the vent is it possible it is condensing on the drywall where it is in contact with the vent?

Comment: @Gil. I  think I can see the streaks go to the vent.  Its tbe angle of the photo causing oart of ig to reflect.

Comment: Are you in the southern hemisphere?